# Does the sum of numbers depend on the sequence in which they are added?

Tags: java, concurrency

It was my intuition so far that sum for a set of numbers is independent of the order in which they are added. In the following, the set of random numbers is determined by the seed=0, but the sequence is determined by the order of execution in threads.

I would like to use the sum of a large number doubles from a multi-threaded computation as a checksum. Is there a way to find a rounding scheme for the sum that is maximally sensitive to the constituent numbers in the sum, but insensitive to the particular random sequence of additions?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Test implements Callable<Double> {

    public static class Sum {

        double sum = 0;

        public synchronized void add(double val) {
            sum += val;
        }

        public double getSum() {
            return sum;
        }
    };
    Sum sum;

    public Test(Sum sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    @Override
    public Double call() {
        Random rand = new Random(0);
        for (long i = 0; i < 1000000L; i++) {
            sum.add(rand.nextDouble());
        }
        return 0D;
    }

    static double mean() {
        Sum sum = new Sum();
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
        ArrayList<Future<Double>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        double x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
            Test test = new Test(sum);
            results.add(pool.submit(test));
        }

        for (Future<Double> entry : results) {
            try {
                x += entry.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted.", ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Excecution exception:");
            }
        }

        pool.shutdown();

        return sum.getSum();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.format("Avg:%22.20f\n", mean());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend adding `double`s since it can result in loss of precision. Instead, use `long` or `BigDecimal`. And no, remember a basic rule when adding numbers: *the order of the factors does not affect the product*.

Comment: Try the example ... order does seem to effect the sum.

Comment: The synchronized method should take care of threading issues. So this should even happen with just one "core". I can imagine that adding doubles works differently depending on order because of differing effects of rounding errors.

Comment: try it out ... doesn't happen with one core.

Comment: So, is there an operation that will work as a has for a large number of doubles?

Comment: It probably *does work* (according to the spec for floating points which does not support handling unlimited precision).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data structures are properly synchronised, the order should not affect the final sum, *provided that the operations are commutative.*

In other words, provided that `a + b` is identical to `b + a`.

That's *not* always the case with floating point numbers since they are, after all, an approximation of the number you want.

Adding *two* numbers (`a` and `b` above) is probably commutative but it becomes more complex when the quantity of numbers becomes bigger.

For example, if you add the smallest possible number to a (relatively) large number, the fact that you only have a certain precision means that you'll end up with the larger number, for example:

```
      -20
1 + 10     => 1
```

So, if you add `10-20` to `1` a lot of times (10<sup>20</sup> to be exact), you'll still end up with `1`:

```
      -20    -20    -20        -20    -20    -20
1 + 10   + 10   + 10   ... + 10   + 10   + 10      => 1
    \__________________________________________/
                      20
                    10   of these
```

However, if you first add together all those `10-20` values, you'll end up with `1` <sup>(a)</sup>, then adding `1` to that will give you `2`:

```
  -20    -20    -20        -20    -20    -20
10   + 10   + 10   ... + 10   + 10   + 10    + 1   => 2
\__________________________________________/
                  20
                10   of these
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This isn't necessarily *quite* true since the accumulated amount will stop increasing as soon as it becomes large enough relative to `10-20` for that value to have zero effect on it.

However, it *won't* be at the point where the accumulated amount is zero so you should see a difference in the final sums.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronized method should take care of threading issues. So this should even happen with just one "core".

I can imagine that adding doubles works differently depending on order because of differing effects of rounding errors.

For example, BIG + 1 is probably the same as BIG + 2, which violates basic arithmetic sanity. That's floating points for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding doubles of wildly differing magnitudes, you should sort them first by absolute value and start with the smallest.